# When and how would you use a set entry type with the verbose biblatex styles?

Tags: biblatex

The `set` entry type seems to behave in a pretty odd way for the the verbose styles in `biblatex`. When and how might you use this feature? (I'm trying to decide whether to support sets in `biblatex-sbl` and if so how.)

Consider this example which seems very counter-intuitive to me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\cite[postnote]{set}\par
\cite[2859]{herrmann}\par
\cite[3027]{aksin}\par
\cite[2409]{yoon}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think a `@set` really makes sense for `verbose`-like styles. It mainly is there to group several references into one numeric label (I'm led to believe chemists go crazy for those sort of things, others maybe not so much).

Comment: @moewe, I suspected this. I think I'll implement it, but in a slightly more clever way than than the standard verbose styles do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main use for the `@set` entry types is in `numeric`-like styles where it can be convenient to subsume several entries under one citation label (number). Especially with end-note-like styles that are used in chemistry that can make sense.

With `verbose`-like styles I don't really see the appeal of this construction, especially if we keep in mind that `biblatex` already has a great `related`-mechanism to deal with related entries.