# Use biblatex's citeauthor command in combination with entry sets

Tags: biblatex

While working with `entry sets` in combination with the `\citeauthor` command I have encountered an undesired bahaviour. 
As shown in the following MWEB refering to a single entry of an entry set using the `\cite` command works fine, while `\citauthor` gives the name of the author of the first entry, even while refering to the second entry.

Is there a possibility to overcome this behaviour?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[sorting=none,sortcites=true,block=none,citestyle=numeric-comp,bibstyle=chem-angew,giveninits=true,autocite=superscript,subentry=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{First,
author = {First, A.},
journal = {Journal},
pages = {1762--1776},
volume = {27},
year = {2017}
}
@article{Second,
author = {Second, B.},
journal = {Journal},
pages = {1762--1776},
volume = {27},
year = {2017}
}
\end{filecontents}

\defbibentryset{set}{First,Second}

\begin{document}

\cite{set}

\citeauthor{First} \cite{First} % yields First [1a]

\citeauthor{Second} \cite{Second} % yields First [1b]

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't the point of an entry set that it is cited as a single item in the bibliography? That is, if you create an entry set, it should be something you wish to treat as a single item, rather than as multiple items. It seems to me that you don't want an entry set here. Why do you think you do?

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. However, I don't think there is any straightforward way to do this. However, there probably is and, if so, moewe will probably know it.

Comment: This is a little similar to `biblatex` [issue #470](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/470)

Comment: An also, this question I asked a while ago: [When and how would you use a set entry type with the verbose biblatex styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340231/when-and-how-would-you-use-a-set-entry-type-with-the-verbose-biblatex-styles). It seems like once a `set` is defined, you can never refer to individual entries.

Comment: In the document I am currently writing, I wold like to cite an amout of sources that proove the same statement. For this porpous I want to use an entry set. However I later on want to differentiate between thouse sources, as there are slight difference which I would like to highlight, so I need to cite specific entries of this entry set. I hope this explanation made clearer why I need this combination of commands. 
@David Purton Thank you for posting the link to github and as well for posting there what I have enountered. 
For now it seems as if I had to wait for an update of the package.

Comment: You can try biblatex 3.8 DEV version from Sourceforge (you'll need biber 2.8 DEV version too). I have refactored the data fetching for set members in citations as this was the culprit. Your example should work with the new version. Please add any problems to https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/470

Comment: @PLK Thanks a lot for this fast update. Regarding the problem that I described in my question, everything works just fine using the updated package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in `biblatex` 3.8 (currently in DEV on Sourceforge).

*Technical explanation*: This was a long-standing issue with the way data for set members were retrieved in biblatex. For some reason, the decision was taken a long time ago to simply retrieve all of the set parent data when citing a set member. Since for various legacy bibtex reasons, the set parent is basically just a copy of the first set member, this explains the bad behaviour. The only purpose of having such dummy set parent data is to provide a home for the crucial `labelnumber/labelalpha/labelprefix` fields which are attached to the set parent. biblatex 3.8 no longer uses set parent data when citing set members. It retains the set member data but injects the critical parent data into the child data.

Comment: Is there a workaround if i have to work with an older version (Overleaf)?